# calculate IGRF with pyigrf and export to csv

Tags: python, list

I want to calculate some data with pyIGRF library but when I export it to csv all data have same parameters.

```
import pyIGRF
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('D:/IGRF')
df=pd.read_csv('igrf.csv')
print(df)
df.head()
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    x=[Inc,Dec,Hi,Xn,Yn,Zn,totalmag]=pyIGRF.igrf_value(df['lan'][i],df['lat'][i],df['alt'][i],2022)
    for j in x:
        df['Inc']=Inc
        df['Dec']=Dec
        df['total']=totalmag

print(df)
import csv
df.to_csv('IGRF_end.csv')
```

I think loop needs some changes, but I couldn't find this changes.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see when looking at the pyIGRF documentation is that you've got the order of the inputs wrong.  It should be:

```
pyIGRF.igrf_variation(lat, lon, alt, date)
```

And you've switched the latitude and longitude.